# Accessing vectors in common lisp

Tags: common-lisp, ansi-common-lisp

```
(setf vec (make-array 4 :initial-element nil))
(svref vec 0)
```

In the above snippet we create a vector of length 4 and access its elements by (svref vec ).

```
(vector 1 2 3 4 5)
```

In the above snippet we create a vector of length 5 using vector function. How do we access the elements of this vector? How svref is used for this vector?

Comment: it's `:initial-element` btw

Comment: Why do you quote numbers?

Comment: Hope this helps: https://lispcookbook.github.io/cl-cookbook/data-structures.html#arrays-and-vectors

Answer (score 6):

The generic vector reference function is `aref`, the same as for all other arrays.

`Svref` is only for *simple vectors*, i. e. vectors with `element-type` `t`, not adjustable, no fill-pointer, not displaced.

By the way, `vector` does produce a simple vector, so `svref` should work for your second example, too.

Other issues:

- I guess you mean `:initial-element`.
- No need to quote number literals, they evaluate to themselves.